# Is there a dependency injection framework for asp net mvc that like spring framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

bean id="foo" class="com.ems.samples.spring.Foo"
  property name="bar" ref="bar"/
/bean
bean id="bar" class="com.ems.samples.spring.Bar"

```
       public class Foo {

  private Bar bar;

  public String getMessage() {

        return "Foo" + bar.getMessage();

  }

  public void setBar(Bar bar) {

        this.bar = bar;

  }
```

}

public class Bar {

```
  public String getMessage() {


        return "Bar";

  }
```

}

Comment: why would it be different for MVC in the first place. DI is a generic pattern to decouple classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's [Castle Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/container/index.html), [Spring.NET](http://www.springframework.net/), [StructureMap](http://structuremap.sourceforge.net/Default.htm), [Unity](http://www.codeplex.com/unity), [Ninject](http://ninject.org/) and possibly more... check out the [MvcContrib](http://www.codeplex.com/MVCContrib) project for samples and controller factories that support the mentioned IoC containers.

Answer (score 2):

checkout Munq.DI at [munq.codeplex.com](http://munq.codeplex.com). It is a simple, fast DI container with lifetime managers specific to web development.  Object can have lifetime duration of Request, Session, Cache, and Container.  Additionally, there is a MunqControllerFactory and example for ASP.NET MVC.  Full source included.

Comment: i think all of DI frameworks gives poor performance.
i can injection manually because the frameworks become for lazy code compiling :)

Comment: Not all DI have poor performance, but some do.  check out  Daniel Cazzulino's Blog postings on Funq http://www.clariusconsulting.net/blogs/kzu/archive/2009/04/17/141951.aspx.  Some interesting performance information.  Munq is slightly faster than Funq due to simpler Resolve functionality (no parameters).  Properly used, a IOC can completely decouple class construction from the concrete instances of the class's dependencies.  This allows you to inject stubs or alternate implementations for testing or different environments.

Answer (score 0):

There's [Spring.net](http://www.springframework.net/) for a start, but I've no idea how it plays with asp.net mvc

Comment: thanx but i know it ,i need for asp net mvc.

Comment: oh yes
spring.net
i saw only spring word first.